# React native maps mapView maxZoomLevel unexpected behavior

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I'm setting MapView maxZoomLevel to 15. When component renders map in iOS zooms in 20 and then zooms out 15. And every time component re-renders it's doing the same.

Comment: Please post the relevant minimal reproducible example code in your question, don’t post it somewhere else on the internet; make it easy for people to help you and you’ll get more and better answers. How to post a Stack Snippet (in your question): meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/7515189

Comment: @SHG21 just take code from https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps/tree/master/example and add maxZoomLevel prop different then 20. **REMEMBER** it zooms in and out only in iOS.

Comment: Hi @Sergey,
What I am saying is proper way to post questions on stack overflow is to post your code here.
People who are trying to help do not want to click on unknown urls to go find your code.
You will get a lot more help if you follow stack overflow best practices.
Thanks.